# winsock select based server

Tags: select, winsock

I need an example of select based server, which receives and sends data from/to a client.
I prefer MSDN example but I could not find any on MSDN.

There is a good one here;
http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/examples/basics/select-server.html

But my implementation is almost same, except for, I did not set ExceptFDs, it is null. I set select function's timeout to 250 ms.

And when one client is connected and server is sending data to client, there is no problem. It is working for weeks without problem.
But when client also sends data server, after appr. 5 hours,at the line of select function STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW exception occurs.

I am really stuck. I will be appreciated for any advice.
Many Thanks

Comment: I've found myself banging my head against a brick wall when it comes to Microsoft and select() - it's almost as if Microsoft really hates cross-platform approaches to programming!

Comment: Whatever you do, don't assume that a Microsoft select() statement will do what you expect.

Comment: :S so what can I do? What kind of brick? Can you a little explain? Maybe it can help me. Because there is a huge application running on a select based communication layer. :(